# Explicit Template Specialization With Enumerated Types

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I have a class whose implementation differs (slightly) depending on a said multiplier. Basically, it will ultimately be a serial data packet. When placed in ASCII mode, the width of a number of bit-fields will double and those fields will differ in format.

Unfortunately, since I'd like to make use of `std::bitset`, I cannot declare the widths dynamically. The most reasonable approach I could muster up was to use templates instead. I'd like to separate the template definition from the implementation. As such, I've done the following:

*My_Bytestream.hpp*

```
#define NUMBITS(x) (x*sizeof(uint8_t))

enum My_BytestreamType
{
    BINARY = 1,
    ASCII = 2
};

template <My_BytestreamType MULTIPLIER>
class My_Bytestream
{
public:
    My_Bytestream(My_Flag_t flags, My_Command_t command);

private:

    boost::optional<std::bitset<NUMBITS(2 * MULTIPLIER) >> m_address;
    boost::optional<std::bitset<NUMBITS(2 * MULTIPLIER) >> m_CRC;
};
```

*MyBytestream.tpp*

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "My_Bytestream.hpp"

template <My_BytestreamType MULTIPLIER> class My_Bytestream;

template<>
My_Bytestream<My_BytestreamType::BINARY>::My_Bytestream(My_Flag_t flags, My_Command_t command)
{
    m_command = command;
}
```

However, this results in the following **linker** error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall My_Bytestream<1>::My_Bytestream<1>(enum My_Flag_t,enum My_Command_t)" (??0?$My_Bytestream@$00@@QAE@W4My_Flag_t@@W4My_Command_t@@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall My_Binary_Command::My_Binary_Command(enum My_Flag_t,enum My_Command_t)" (??0My_Binary_Command@@QAE@W4My_Flag_t@@W4My_Command_t@@@Z)
```

Note that `My_Flag_t` and `My_Command_t`are defined as (unrelated) enumerations in another header.

Comment: You did the includes wrong.  At the bottom of the .h file you need to include the .tpp file.  Think of the tpp file as an extension of the header.

Comment: @NathanOliver perfect, it worked.Thanks